# How do I redirect from /index.php/event/* to /event?

Tags: 7, uri

I have old links, for example the following ones.

- index.php/event/nr1
- index.php/event/nr2

If users are coming on index.php/event/*, they should be redirected to 
/event.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Match Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect) module.
**How to use:**
1) Enable module as usual
2) Go to configuration page /admin/config/search/match_redirect
3) Add redirect settings there
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `if(!empty(arg(1))) { drupal_goto('events')}`

You can write this in any of your custom module using hook `modulename_init()` function.

In your case the argument number may change, please do check and change the argument number.

Answer (score 0):

There are Rewrite Rules that can be used to achieve the same thing on drupal 7 as well as on drupal 8. Use this Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file located in Drupal Root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php/event/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/event [L,R=301]
```