# redirect using *

Tags: redirection

I have pages in path try/* and I would like to redirect to node/20.
I tried path auto but using * is not allowed, I have to specify one by one.

Is there any module or way to redirect try/* to node/20

Comment: Check my answer about [Match Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect) module there: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/196443/19401

Comment: Yes thanks. Sorry for the similar question. In my case it works if I enable "Allow content to be redirected".

Answer (score 1):

Use drupal [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) and [drupal_match_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7) api to check the path and redirect to your defined path.

So in your case,

```
if (drupal_match_path(current_path(), 'try/*')) {
  drupal_goto('node/20');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect from `.htaccess` directly.

```
RewriteRule ^try/(.*)    node/20   [R=301,L]
```

Place the rule from above in the .htaccess file, the next line after `RewriteEngine on`

Answer (score -1):

Implement the hook [hook_boot](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) in your custom module. This hook gets invoked for every page request. In the hook you may implement the code to match the pattern of the request URI by using preg_match or by implementing the logic suggested by @manikandan kannan . You can then redirect using the code

```
header('Location: '.$GLOBALS['base_url'].'/node/20');
```