# How do I redirect users visiting a path matching a regular expression?

Tags: 8, uri, redirection

My question is the same asked in [How do I redirect from /index.php/event/* to /event?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196438/how-to-redirect-with-wildcard) but for Drupal 8.

Since the module suggested in the accepted answer for that question doesn't have a version for Drupal 8, how can I achieve the same with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8 you use an event subscriber for this. You subscribe to a REQUEST kernel event, get the original url from the request, apply a regular expression and if this finds a replacement set the new url as a 301 redirect response.

**mymodule/src/EventSubscriber/RedirectSubscriber.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function redirectIndexPHP(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $old_url = $event->getRequest()->getUri();
    $new_url = preg_replace('|/index.php|', '', $old_url, 1, $count);
    if ($count > 0) {
      $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($new_url, 301);
      $event->setResponse($response);
    }
  }

  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('redirectIndexPHP', 39);
    return $events;
  }

}
```

**mymodule/mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  mymodule.redirect:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\RedirectSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it as follows (untested):

```
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

function somePageCallback()
{
   ...

   return new RedirectResponse('/path/to/redirect/to');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Rewrite Rule to be written in .htaccess file located in Drupal Root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php/event/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/event [L,R=301]
```

Hope, it makes sense to you.

Comment: `.htaccess` files usually pushed up with core changes and are prone to getting overwritten.