# How to redirect a node to an external URL?

Tags: 8

Is there a way to "alias" a Drupal site node to an external URL?

I'd like that a click on a link in my Drupal site like 'http://mysite/node/64' redirects to an address like 'http://anothersite/whateverurl'.

I use [Fullcalendar View](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar_view) module.
I added a Date range field to a custom content of mine (my modified Basic page).
If I set a date in a node of that type, I can see an item linked to it in the Calendar:
[image]
If I click on the item, I am redirected to the corresponding node and I see its content.
For some nodes, I'd like the link to point to an external url instead...

[Edit]
I tried something else: I created a new View with no fields at all except the Daterange.
When I use Format: `Unformatted list`, I get this result:
[image]
which is OK as I have only one node of the type filtered.
When I use Format: `Full Calendar Display`, I get this result:
[image]
which is strange as I have no fields in the View description pointing to the node itself...
Does it mean that Fullcalendar View] module generates its magic elsewhere?
I'm a bit confused :-(
Any help?

Comment: If you're redirecting why would you also have a node? Can't you just redirect the URL at vhost/.htaccess level?

Comment: Or with the same result in a request event subscriber, example before routing [How do I redirect users visiting a path matching a regular expression?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223896/47547) , which you can also do with a lower priority after routing to catch aliases of the node.

Comment: Updated my question to clarify why...

Comment: You'd be better off keeping that external URL in a field attached to the node, then overwriting the Views row template to link it based on that value if available

Comment: Any clue how to do that?

Comment: I gave this Fullcalendar module a shot and it seems its not Modular enough to do what I describe below ... if this issue is resolved https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar_view/issues/2972642 or with custom programming it can probably be done.

Comment: In this case, what should be the proper hook_views where I should put my custom code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want this done in a view here is a possible solution

1. Add a `link field` to your content type `external url` which would need to be followed when available otherwise (if empty) it would take to node view (normal behaviour).

Modify the Fullcalendar View and add follow 2 fields

2. `Link to content` hidden
   [image]
3. `external url` and adjust the `No results behaviour` to include `{{ view_node }}` 
   [image]
4. Use `external url` as the link

**NOTE:** it appears that `Fullcallendar view` module takes the link to node in a way that it cannot be modified within the view as described above.  There is a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar_view/issues/2972642) that asks for such an option.  In the meantime perhaps the above can be achieved with another **calendar** module () or modify the URL from within a custom module.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't make your proposal work. I don't understand your 4th point: Use `external url` as the link. How do I do that?

Comment: @gbmapo your calendar view outputs a field that is the actual link. Change that field to use the external URL output instead, you can post a screenshot of your calendar View configuration

Comment: I updated my question...

Comment: I just read your NOTE.  
Any clue where I can put the code in my custom module?  
what should be the proper hook_views to be used?

Comment: @gbmapo I believe this functionality is hardcoded in `template_preprocess_views_view_fullcalendar` function in `fullcalendar_view.theme.inc` file.  Its a template function so you can probably copy paste it in your `THEMENAME.module` and rename it to `THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_fullcalendar`.  I think what needs changing  is on line  154 `'url' => $current_entity->toUrl()->toString(),`

Comment: I added the following [code](https://imgur.com/a/3sxI8VC) in `mytheme_preprocess_views_view_fullcalendar` and it works!  
Thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a node on your website
`example.com/node/123` with an alias to it `example.com/my-node`

If what you need is:

- when a user try to access the node by going to `example.com/node/123`, so he will be redirected to an **external url.**
- but when the user access the node by going to `example.com/my-node`, no redirection and he will normally have access to the **node page**.

If this what you are asking about, reply to my answer here and i will gibe you a full tutorial on how to do it !

Otherwise, as @clive mentioned, your question does not make sense ! And for what you need the node if you are not going to use it.

Comment: Updated my question to clarify why...

Comment: **For some nodes, I'd like the link to point to an external url instead...** does those nodes have in the url anything to distinguish them from the other nodes ? What is the difference between those nodes you want to redirect and the others with no redirection ? (Field, url, title..!?!)

Comment: I thought to create a specific content type for that...

Comment: As very straight solution, you can use rules module or business rules module and create a condition to fire a page redirect action when for example certain arguments are available in the url or when a specific node field = to a specific value. **Meaning:** if the node you want to be redirected to an external url has the **title field** contains for example the world *external* so you can add a **condition** to check the title of every **loaded node**, if the **title contains** tbe word **external* so fire a **page redirect** action to whatever url you want. Hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to do this, as the other answers show.

I wrote a module called "Alien Alias" which does this, it can link to internal or external locations. It also lets you keep stats of the clicks (if you want it to).

(Optionally) it intercepts very early in the page build process to redirect away, although you can let it build a whole page and then redirect.

Here: https://drupal.org/project/alien_alias